# Server-side redirect without calling GET twice

Tags: javascript, redirect, fetch

I'm trying to implement what is basically a multi-step form: submit page 1 with a POST request, then have the user be redirected to page 2 of the form. This ends up making two GET requests (one `fetch` and one `document` GET, looking at the network requests), which I'm not sure is right. Why does the initial GET request not just get the HTML page that should be rendered (the response to the `fetch` request is empty)? Should there actually be two requests in the right pattern for this, or is my understanding of how redirects should work not quite right?

Client code:

```
fetch("/page-1", {
    method: "POST",
    redirect: "follow",
    <...other params here>
}).then(resp => {
    window.location.href = resp.url;
})
```

Flask server code:

```
@app.route("/page-1", methods=["GET", "POST"]
def page_1():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # save page 1 data here
        return redirect(url_for("page-2", _scheme="https", _external=True))
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("page-1.html")

@app.route("/page-2", methods=["GET", "POST"]
def page_2():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # save page 2 data here
    if request.method == "GET":
        # **this code path is called twice every time the user navigates page 1->2
        return render_template("page-2.html")
```

Comment: This seems like you could just use an html form action, and leave the JS out of it. That would take care of the post and the redirect in one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fetch` makes a POST request to `/page-1`
2. The server responds saying "You need to get `page-2` instead"
3. `fetch` follows the redirect and makes a GET request to `/page-2`
4. The server responds with the content of `page-2.html` after passing it through a template engine
5. `fetch` ignores everything about the response except the URL
6. Your JavaScript assigns the URL to `location.href`
7. The browser navigates to that URL, making a GET request to get the content to do so

---

If you want to process the data with `fetch` then call a method like `response.text()` and process the response with JavaScript.

If you want to navigate to the resulting page, then use a regular form submission in the first place. The point of `fetch` is to make HTTP requests *without* leaving the current page.